# Ant task to update a value

Tags: xml, replace

Basically i want to update a value in a xml tag . 
this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application> ten</application>
  <version>1</version>
</appengine-web-app>
```

i want to change the application tag value from ten to someother value ,say three. my code is this

```
<target name="renameconfig"
      description="Renaming config files">
<taskdef name="xmltask" 
            classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>
<xmltask source="war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml" dest="war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml"> 
  <replace path="/:appengine-web-app/:application/text()" withText="three"> </replace>
</xmltask>
  </target>
```

this populate empty value in application tag .ie . It would be great if any one correct this .Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

the XPath should be:

```
 <replace path="/appengine-web-app/application/text()" withText="three"> </replace>
```

or if the namespace is causing trouble:

```
<replace path="/*[namespace-uri()='http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0' and local-name()='appengine-web-app']/*[namespace-uri()='http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0' and local-name()='application']/text()" withText="three"> </replace>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <replace path="/appengine-web-app/application/text()" withText="three"> </replace>
```

for this nothing happens.

for this

```
<replace path="/*[namespace-uri()='http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0' and local-name()='appengine-web-app']/*[namespace-uri()='http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0' and local-name()='application']/text()" withText="three"> </replace>
```

value is setting as empty

Comment: I think you posted a comment to my answer, as an answer.